# Exclusion strategy for RealmObject with Jackson

Tags: android, jackson, gson, realm, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 to retrieve data from an API, and caching them locally with Realm. I have a ServiceFactory class that I use to create all the request to the API. It works flawlessly if the object I download don't extends RealmObject. To download (and deserialize) RealmObject I need to include a custom exclusion strategy to the GsonConverterFactory, like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).create();

retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        [...]
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build();
```

I'm trying to move from Gson to Jackson, but I can't find how to do something like `setExclusionStrategy` **for RealmObject**. I know I can use exclusion with annotation, but that mean I need to add an annotation for every attribute in every class (more than 30 class with ~30 attribute, that will be insane)

EDIT:
I have my model like
    Example extends RealmObject{
        String foo, bar;
        /*getter*/
    }
And a service to download from an api a json that is something like
    {
        foo: 'val1',
        bar: 'val2'
    }
Then my service

```
public interface ExampleService {
    @GET("example/{id}")
    Observable<Example> getExample(@Path("id") int id);
}
```

Then I use `new ServiceFactory(getContext()).createRetrofitService(ExampleService.class).getExample(id)[...]`. If I remove the `extends RealmObject` everything works, but putting it back I get a black screen and crash after some minute.
To fix that I put the exclusion strategy as above. I've also managed to bypass it with Jackson:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    [...]
    .setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(){
        @Override
        public Boolean isIgnorableType(AnnotatedClass ac) {
            if(ac.getRawType().equals(RealmObject.class))
                return true;
            return super.isIgnorableType(ac);
        }
    });
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    [...]
    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(mapper))
    .build();
```

this fixed my issue, I have no idea why I have all these problem but now everything's working fine (I'm having some lag with executeTransactionAsync with 5k record, but that's a different problem)

Comment: Note that the Exclusion strategy was only needed due to a bug in GSON. We haven't heard of any problems combining Realm and Jackson.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior edited, maybe you can explain me why I'm having this issue and I can understand how to use Realm in the correct way :)

Comment: We have an example app here that combines Realm and Jackson, perhaps you can use that to see what your app does differently? https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/newsreaderExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/newsreader/model/network/NYTimesDataLoader.java and https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/newsreaderExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/newsreader/model/entity/NYTimesStory.java